# Rails preventing SQL injections

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am worried that my solution won't be very secure. I am using Rails **4.1.6**

Currently I use:

```
@x = params[:myquery]
Monkey.where("monkeys_name LIKE ?", "%#{@x}%")
```

I want to prevent SQL injections. How do I discover malicious things inside @x ? Are there helpers? Or does Rails something to prevent it underneath the hood?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't be lazy and read documentation http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection

Comment: very constructive comment regarding the lazy part. Thanks for the link though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Rails Security Guide it says that

> Instead of passing a string to the conditions option, you can pass an
>   array to sanitize tainted strings.

```
Monkey.where("monkeys_name LIKE ?", "%#{@x}%")
```

So your string will be sanitized by default and Rails will do the heavy lifting for you in this case.

You can read the detailed guide here especially 7.2.4 is what you looking for.

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection

Comment: thanks a lot - exactly what I expected with the millions of features Rails have!

Comment: Yeah Rails covers your back :)